# Query Builder - whereRaw with subquery

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, query-builder, laravel-5

I need to create the following query using Laravel Query Builder:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM table WHERE 1 < (SELECT count(*) FROM x WHERE y=2)
```

the question is - is it possible to do it using query builder?

The only why I was able to achieve it is:

```
\DB::table('table')->whereRaw('1 < (SELECT count(*) FROM x WHERE y=2)')->count();
```

but this way I need to manually put here subquery and it's generating wrong query:

`SELECT count(*) FROM table WHERE 1 < (SELECT count(*) FROM x WHERE y=2) IS NULL`

(`is null` is added at the end)

Is it possible to use here query builder also for subquery and make it to generate correct SQL?

Comment: Is it not possible to use a closure where for the subquery?

Comment: Sorry if Im wrong but you want the **addNestedWhereQuery**?  http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I found is creating separate query builder this way:

```
$subQuery = \DB::table('x')->selectRaw('count(*)')->where('y',2);

\DB::table('table')->whereRaw('1 < ('.$subQuery->toSql().')')->addBinding($subQuery->getBindings());
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
\DB::table('table')->where(DB::raw('SELECT count(*) FROM x WHERE y=2'), '<',1)->count();
```